# CasperJS code from tutorial does not work

Tags: casperjs

It's my first post here : )
I'm learning CasperJS and I have to write script who search all img's on site and check urls.

I found this tutorial from [vgaltes.com](http://vgaltes.com/)

```
var imagesArray = [];

function getImages() {
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('img[src]');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src');
    });
};

casper.start('http://fooo.fooo', function () {
    imagesArray = this.evaluate(getImages);
    var self = this;
    imagesArray.forEach(function (item) {
        if (self.resourceExists(item)) {
            self.echo(item + ' loaded');
        } else {
            var message = item + ' not loaded';
            self.echo(message, 'ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

but when I run this code on CasperJS (with valid url) do not work. Nothing happens.
Casper Version is 1.1

Comment: "nothing happens" when? when you launch casper js on your script? it just finishes? what's the exit code (ERRORLEVEL or $?)? did you check to see if the document at your given url contains images?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you did not run the function, try adding the below code in the end

```
casper.run(function() {this.test.renderResults(true);});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the owner of vgaltes.com. As Pbk1303 said, you have to call to run function. If you read the tutorial, is the last source code posted.

```
casper.run(function(){
    this.echo('finished');
    this.test.done(1);
    this.test.renderResults(true);
});
```

Regards,

Comment: I have a doubt, the above code does not take the image src from the img tag created dynamically , how do i do it?.

Comment: I don't understand you. What do you mean by "the img tag created dynamically"? In my post, I make a capture of the page and compare it with a reference image from file system.